# Story ID - fantasy novel with a shipwreck and an odd mage

Tags: story-identification

This is a novel I read - possibly only partially - sometime in the late 90s, and during one attempt to move my library or another it slipped out of existence.

- Most of what I can remember is on a ship that gets underway from one city to another.
- One character is some kind of mage who insists he doesn't have magic, he just does "tricks".
- The main character is a friend?/apprentice?/companion? to the odd mage.
- The not-mage has a penchant for producing oranges out of nowhere and offering them to people.
- The ship is shipwrecked and there's some suggestion the mage can get them supplies.  He had something like a portal to a merchant's stall sewn into his bag, but the merchant had moved all his supplies after finding his oranges flooded with seawater.

I've struggled to remember more detail than this.  I had recently started Robin Hobb's Elderlings books, and the Fool's way of talking around Fitz reminded me a bit of this relationship, but the Fool was way too ethereal and magic doesn't work that way in the Elderlings universe (so far).

Comment: I feel like I read this a lonnnnng time ago. This has the tone of Craig Shaw Gardner's [Ebenezum](https://www.goodreads.com/series/49325-the-ebenezum-trilogy) / Wuntvor books.

Comment: The title "shipwreck and an odd mage" made me think of the *first* book in the Riftwar series, where (IIRC) a shipwreck that took place before the main events of the novel forms the catalyst for the connection between the two universes. Ironically, wrong book and wrong shipwreck but right series.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is almost certainly one of Raymond E Feist's Riftwar books. The not-mage you're remembering is Nakor.

https://annex.fandom.com/wiki/Nakor

> He carries a seemingly empty rucksack, though he continually pulls oranges (or apples) from it.

Unfortunately I can't narrow it down further. He appears in many books, and the specific things you remember occur in a few of them.

Edit: in the comments below, three posters have identified the shipwreck as occurring in "**The King's Buccaneer**", which is therefore the answer.

Comment: Pretty sure you're right, digging through the bibliography now.

Comment: Pretty sure this is The King's Buccaneer specifically. They travel to the continent Novindus and are shipwrecked there. Nakor first appears in the previous book Prince of the Blood.

Comment: Agreed, this is The King's Buccaneer. Somewhere in that book, Nakor starts getting apples instead of oranges out of his bag.

Comment: @Moriarty - since no one is putting up a separate answer, go ahead and edit yours, I'll accept.

Comment: The Kings Buccaneer for certain. Shipwreck happens at the end of a long journey across the ocean to another continent while chasing an enemy ship that has abducted a lot of people. They are a few days behind the other vessel (keeping magical track of it) and run into shoals/reefs just of the coast while the other vessel had turned southward in time. They are forced to go over land through a desert to continue the chase after their abducted friends. It is the 5th book of the Riftwar novels. 31 books in the entire series, some (co-)authored by other writes.

Comment: Radhil done. As @Tonny notes there are 31 books in the series. Many of these feature Nakor and his orange tricks, which is why I had trouble IDing the specific novel.

Comment: @Moriarty Both the shipwreck and the change from oranges to apples lock this in. There is another important shipwreck in a later novel and several ships sunk during naval battles (in this and other novels in the series), but not in combination with the apples.