# Fantasy Novel. One character can always pull an orange from his pocket

Tags: story-identification, novel, teleportation

The other characters are puzzled by this ability for a long time. Then he explains that there is a small magic portal between his pocket and a fruit trader's storehouse. It comes out by a very large pile of oranges and he never takes enough for it to be noticed.

Once when they are all thirsty in a desert and the oranges would be a lifesaver, the portal is not working. I think maybe because his coat got soaked with seawater in a shipwreck.
Maybe the fruit seller was shocked at his oranges being soaked in seawater and moved the pile.
I read it in the 90s.

Comment: https://midkemia.fandom.com/wiki/Nakor

Comment: Likely a dupe of [Story ID - fantasy novel with a shipwreck and an odd mage](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/274515/20774). Mentions the oranges and the shipwreck.

Comment: Yes, this is it 

Comment: Since you've agreed in a comment that this is a duplicate as ID'd by @Valorum, I'm gonna close it as such.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - Another happy landing.